# Obtener objetos de un JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Acabo de hacer un `Parse` a un texto en formato JSON entero. Ahora necesito obtener dichos valores, y puedo sacar el título sin problemas, pero cuando comienza en JSON a recorrer niveles más bajos me parece imposible:

```js
const arr = [
  {
"title": "Titulo 1",
"power": {
  "0": {
    "type": "P1",
    "value": "0001"
  },
  "1": {
    "type": "P1.2",
    "value": "0002"
  }
},
"energy": {
  "0": {
    "type": "E.1",
    "value": "0001"
  }
}
  },
  {
"title": "Titulo 2",
"power": {
  "0": {
    "type": "P2",
    "value": "0001"
  },
  "1": {
    "type": "P2.2",
    "value": "0002"
  },
  "2": {
    "type": "P2.3",
    "value": "0003"
  }
},
"energy": {
  "0": {
    "type": "E2",
    "value": "0001"
  }
}
  }
];

function sndTo( dat ){
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{
        console.log('Title: ' + form.title);
        console.log('POWER');
        console.log('Type: ' + form.power[0].type);
        console.log('Value: ' + form.power[0].value);
        console.log('ENERGY');
        console.log('Type: ' + form.energy[0].type);
        console.log('Value: ' + form.energy[0].value);
        console.log(' ');
         })(dat[n])
      }
}

sndTo( arr )
```

**[EDIT]**

Una vez conseguido sacar el valor 0 de cada uno de los titulos, me gustaría que, si hay más datos por encima de ese 0, los sacase también. Asumo que es con un bucle for, pero no se ni siquiera qué valor contar como lenght.
He probado intentando sacar el número de inputs con nombre `t_power`con lenght, pero me ha sido imposible (dentro del `HTML`).

¿Cómo podría sacar el número de valores que hay para cada title?

Comment: Pero ese html y ese css lo he puesto para el que quiera, que pueda ver cómo funciona. Ese reload lo he puesto para limpiar los datos del formulario, y cuando obtenga los valores del JSON, voy a pegarlos dentro.

Comment: Pero al hacer el reload, aunque sea de toda la página, los valores los puedo seguir sacando en todas mis pruebas. El title, digo, los demás nanai. Igualmente estuve probando a intentar hacer reload solo al formulario, pero no me salía, y como el resultado me seguía dando, decidí seguir con ello, me preocuparía mas tarde.

Comment: El JSON lo parseo, y una vez parseado necesito sacar los valores como el título, el power.type, power.value
Y no me sale, por el 0 que tiene de por medio creo

Comment: TypeError: form[0] is undefined (puesto con y sin comillas)

Comment: Te he editado la pregunta para que veas lo que es un [mcve]. Seguro que pronto recibirás buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Ah vale, ¡¡¡muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que analizar qué estructura tienes en el objeto obtenido:

- Tienes un array de objetos (en el ejemplo tiene sólo un objeto).
- El objeto dentro del array tiene tres propiedades: `title`, `power` y `energy`. El primero es un string, los otros dos son objetos (aunque podrían ser arrays, usar  números como propiedades no me parece muy útil).

Por tanto la función tendría que ser algo como:

```
function sndTo( dat ){
  for(let n in dat){
     (form=>{
        console.log(form);
        console.log(form.title);
        console.log(form.power);
        console.log(form.power[0].type);
        console.log(form.energy[0].type);
     })(dat[n])
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha servido a las mil perfecciones. Me parece increíble que, después de todo lo que he probado, no se me haya ocurrido quitar el punto después de power

Comment: ahora me surge otra duda, si tengo más de un tipo, tendría que ponerlo dentro de un bucle for, verdad?
Es decir, imaginemos que en el titulo UNO, tengo dos power, 0{power:type, value}, 1{power:type, value}
Debería añadir un bucle que por cada 'power' que tenga, me añada uno, no?

Comment: @Pablo Lozano Tengo una duda, lo que se esta haciendo "`(form => {})(data[n])`" solo es para reemplazar el `dat[n]` por el `form` nomas? O tiene otra funcionalidad? Por otro lado tiene un nombre esto? para ver mas del tema

Comment: Primera duda: sí, tendrías que iterar. Por eso comento que mejor usar un array. Segunda duda: es una función "inline inmediatamente invocada (en inglés *IIFE* o *Immediately-invoked Function Expression*)... y sí, en este caso no aporta más que eso.